# How do I place an image with a mouse-click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

To elaborate, if I click somewhere on the page, an image (that I add in the code) will be placed. I couldn't find any information on anything similar to this online. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event listeners for the 'click' event. Create an image, set the relative url and append it to your document.

Something like this for example.

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.setAttribute('src','http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png');

    e.target.appendChild(img);
});
```

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wPUK7/).

This is just a basic example by the way. You need to elaborate it to assure cross-browser compatibility, perhaps consider image preloading, etc.

Comment: Would that place the image where the user clicks or just at some random place in the page?

Comment: Where the user clicks. e.target refers to the element being clicked. In my example, the element being clicked must be an element with id="foo". Change "foo" with the ID of the element you want to click.

Comment: I tried it and a mouse click doesn't place the image. You can view the code here, http://pastebin.com/5LsX8u70. As for the finished result, http://soulsnatcher.bplaced.net/bingo.html .

Comment: It doesn't work because you are trying to place an image as a child of another image, which is not allowed because image elements cannot have any children. Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BFYF7/6/). The image is inserted into the body. The problem is you probably want the image to appear on a specified clicked square. To do this, you need to have one element for each square you have, and assign a 'src' property when it's clicked.

Comment: Thanks! So if I were to make a number of images for each individual square, and assign a 'src' property, it should work?

Comment: @SS': Yes, that's the idea. Try to do it yourself to make some practice, then if you have problems or any doubt write back here and I will address your issues! :)